# How to append items to a file that contains a json array?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to append `user_id` to `user_blacklist.json`:

```
def follow(self, user_id):
    with open('user_blacklist.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(user_id, fp)
```

`user_blacklist.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "user_blacklist": [
      "1691998847",
      "1691998847",
      "APPEND_NEW_ID_HERE"
    ]
}
```

But as you can see, I'm overwriting the whole file with `user_id`, instead of appending to the list. I'm sure it's easy, but I have zero experience with Python.

Comment: `data = json.load(...) ; data['user_blacklist'].append(user_id) ; json.dump(data, ...)`

Comment: Mmmmmmmmm, i can not understand why you are asking such question,?you already have 14.9K !

Comment: @pylover Just because I have 14.9K doesn't mean I know Python.

Comment: Just kidding bro..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read all json, add element and save all json.

```
with open('user_blacklist.json', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

data['user_blacklist'].append(user_id)

with open('user_blacklist.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

Comment: Thanks. Wow, Python is so beautiful and simple compared to JavaScript. It's a pity it isn't the default scripting language for the browser.